# Solve for $D$ in $R^{T}DSDR = Id$

Tags: linear-solver, matrix

Given that $R$ is a rectangular matrix, $D$ is a diagonal, square matrix and $S$ being a square matrix along with the fact that both $D$ and $S$ are invertible. $S$ in this specific case can be assumed to be symmetric, positive-definite.

$R$ is actually the first few columns of the discrete Fourier Transform matrix. Thus, $R^{T}R=Id $. Note $RR^{T}$ need not be $Id$. Also, $R$ has both dimensions of the same order (but with more rows than columns). $R$ also has a full row rank.

I would like to obtain $D$ in terms of the given matrices, which are $R$ and $S$

Comment: How can $R$ be invertible if it's rectangular?

Comment: Also, is $S$ symmetric, positive definite, invertible? Is $R$ a tall or a wide rectangular matrix?

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect changes. $S$ is indeed symmetric, positive-definite. Both dimensions of $R$ are of the same order but with more rows than columns.

Comment: $D$ will not be unique in general. Think for example of the case where $S=id$ and $R$ is a single column.

Comment: Thanks. In case where $S=Id$, and $R$ is a single column, i.e., a vector of ones because it is the first column of the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix, we are left with $\sum_{i} D_{i}^{2} = 1$ and the solution is indeed not unique.

Comment: Vectorization can probably help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics). Maybe you can solve for $Y$ in $R^\top YR=I$ first and find $D$ given $Y=DSD$ should be easy. However, I guess $Y$ will have lots of degree of freedom and not all will satisfy $DSD=Y$ for diagonal $D$